# refreshing component on get method with vuejs

Tags: javascript, components, reload, vuejs2

I Have a component which parse a json file on mounted phase.
The problem is :
when I click on a button , a send another GET method to get another json file and transmit it to my compoment.
the problem is that the component don't reload itself with the new props and my component display the old values
If someone know how to refresh components , here is my code

```
<template>
  <div class="perturbo">
    <div class="col-md-3 btnMenu">
      <button v-for="item,index in perturboButtonData.button_list" type="button"
              v-bind:style="'background:white'"
              class="btn-lg btn-block myBtnClass"
              @click="activeButton(index)">
        {{item.label}}
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="row">
        <graphe
          v-for="ana,index in perturboData.ANA"
          :key="ana.id"
          :data="ana"
          :index="index"
          type="number"
          :timeSpec="perturboData.liste_dates">
        </graphe>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <graphe
          v-for="dig,index in perturboData.DIG"
          :key="dig.id"
          :index="index"
          :data="dig"
          type="number"
          isDigit="YES"
          :timeSpec="perturboData.liste_dates">
        </graphe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>



<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import Graphe from './Graphe/Graphe.vue'
  export default {
    name: 'perturbo',
    components : {
      'graphe' : Graphe
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        isActivated: false,
        perturboData: {},
        perturboButtonData: {}
      }
    },
    methods: {
      activeButton : function (index) {
          console.log(this.perturboButtonData)
        axios.get('./static/cgi/' + this.perturboButtonData.button_list[index].link)
          .then((response) => {
            this.perturboData = response.data;
            this.isActivated = true

          })
      }
    },
    mounted : function () {
      axios.get('./static/cgi/format_json_perturbo.json')
        .then((response) => {
          this.perturboButtonData = response.data;
        })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here is the code of my graphe component

```
<template>
  <div class="graphe">
        <vue-chart
          :chart-events="chartEvents"
          :columns="columns"
          :rows="rows"
          chart-type="LineChart"
          :options="options">
        </vue-chart>
  </div>
</template>



<script>
  export default {
    name: 'graphe',
    props: {
      data: {},
      timeSpec : Array,
      index: Number,
      type: String,
      isDigit:String,
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        chartEvents: {
          'select': function() {

          },
          'ready': function() {
          }
        },
        rows: [],
        columns: [],
        options: {
          title: this.data.name,
          hAxis: {

          },
          vAxis: {
            ticks : []
          },
          width: 650,
          height: 350,
          curveType : 'function'
        }
      }
    },
    methods:  {
      normaliseData : function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.timeSpec.length; i++) {
          this.rows[i] = []
          this.rows[i][0] = parseFloat(this.timeSpec[i])
        }
        this.columns[0] = { 'type': 'number', 'label': 'time' }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.data.data.length; i++){
          this.columns[i+1] = {'type': this.type ,'label': this.data.data[i].name}
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.timeSpec.length; i++) {
          for (let y = 0; y < this.data.data.length; y++) {
            this.rows[i][y+1] = parseFloat(this.data.data[y].data[i])
          }
        }
        if (this.isDigit == "YES"){
          this.digRow(this.rows)
          for (let v = 0; v < this.data.data.length; v ++){
            this.options.vAxis.ticks[v] =  { v: v, f:  this.data.data[v].name}
          }
          this.options.curveType = ''
        }
      },
      digRow : function (rowTab) {

        let newRow = []
        let lengthMax = rowTab.length
        let rowTmp = []
        let index = 0

        for (let i = 0; i < lengthMax; i ++){
            rowTmp[index] = []
            rowTmp[index][0] = rowTab[i][0]
            for(let y = 1; y < rowTab[i].length; y ++){
              rowTmp[index][y] = rowTab[i][y] + y - 1
            }
            if (i + 1 !== rowTab.length)
            {

              newRow = rowTmp[index].slice()
              newRow[0] = rowTab[i+1][0]
              rowTmp.splice(index+1,0,newRow)
              index = index + 2
            }
        }
        this.rows = rowTmp
      }
    },
    mounted: function () {
//        // pour les colones
        this.normaliseData()
      }
  }
</script>
```

EDIT : I know where the problem is :
The data received from the parent is treated just once on the mounted function ! , that's why it doesn't reload on change
Should I use a watcher on props ? how can I do that

Comment: Show your actual code pls. namely `perturboData` and `activeButton` declarations.

Comment: @wostex I just updated with the two json I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a method to normalize the data, use a computed property for your `rows`, `columns` and `options` properties. This way, it will update automatically if any of the dependent properties change.

For example, your `options` property could be a computed property that looks like this:

```
computed: {
  options() {
    let options = {
      title: this.data.name,
      hAxis: {

      },
      vAxis: {
        ticks : []
      },
      width: 650,
      height: 350,
      curveType : 'function'
    };

    if (this.isDigit == "YES"){
      this.digRow(this.rows)
      for (let v = 0; v < this.data.data.length; v ++){
        options.vAxis.ticks[v] =  { v: v, f:  this.data.data[v].name}
      }
      options.curveType = ''
    }

    return options;
  }
}
```

Now, whenever `this.data`, `this.isDigit`, or `this.rows` changes, the `options` property will update as well.

Your `rows` and `columns` properties would look like this:

```
rows() {
  let rows = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < this.timeSpec.length; i++) {
    rows[i] = []
    rows[i][0] = parseFloat(this.timeSpec[i])

    for (let y = 0; y < this.data.data.length; y++) {
      rows[i][y+1] = parseFloat(this.data.data[y].data[i])
    }
  }

  return rows;
},
columns() {
  let columns = [];
  columns[0] = { 'type': 'number', 'label': 'time' }

  for (let i = 0; i < this.data.data.length; i++) {
    columns[i+1] = {'type': this.type ,'label': this.data.data[i].name}
  }

  return columns;
},
```

Comment: thank you @thanksd you just answer my question and made me understand how computed var works !! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your changed property won't force view update

> To react to state changes, it’s usually better to use a computed
>   property or watcher.

Try this variant

```
watch: {
    timeSpec(){
    //do something
    //this.normaliseData()
    }
}
```